# Confused to Django customer permission

Tags: django

I am learning Django tutorial. In its official documentation, A example is provided as below code:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("view_task", "Can see available tasks"),
            ("change_task_status", "Can change the status of tasks"),
            ("close_task", "Can remove a task by setting its status as closed"),
        )
```

By doing this,three different type of custom permission associated with Task model are created. If a user want to get any of permission to access this model, how the user get permission to access the Task model? Do I need a these three permission into the user model?

Comment: what happened next? did you manage to sort it out?

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the django documentation for [custom permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions).

> Your code is in charge of checking the value of these permissions when
>   a user is trying to access the functionality provided by the
>   application (viewing tasks, changing the status of tasks, closing
>   tasks.) Continuing the above example, the following checks if a user
>   may view tasks:
>
> `user.has_perm('app.view_task')`

How these permissions are granted or how these permission are checked is entirely upto you. For example you can choose to asign these permissions at signup by listening to a signal. Or you can login to the admin area and manually assign permissions, or you can use a small script to asign permissions to many users etc etc